# WooCommerce how to checkout a product without adding it to the cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to implement this in my website:

Having a second button on a single product next to the"Add to cart" button, let that button be "Buy now".

When the add to cart button is clicked, the product will be added to the cart, when the Buy now button is clicked the client will be redirected to the checkout page where he will only checkout that single product, and that product will not be added to the cart.

For example, if the client was having products A and B in the cart, and clicks the Buy now o product C, he will only checkout for that product, and C will never be added to the cart.

I was thinking of a way to implement this, and I thought that having two different checkout pages might help,.. I don't know if it can, if you have a solution on how I can do this, I'd love to hear from you.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the YITH One Click Checkout: https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-one-click-checkout/

Comment: That one works only on the logged in users, is it possible to configure it so that non logged in users can access it too??

Comment: You could if you wrote one that used LocalStorage instead of a user account, but then the user doesn't really benefit from that (has to enter her information anyway)

Comment: Just reauested by my client, and i failed to do this. Just want to make it work even on the non logged in users

Comment: Hi Nathan, do you have any other suggestions??

Comment: You can let the customer make a purchase without registering, but they still have to enter their information, using login is easier and faster. See Amazon's cart...

Comment: I know, but that's what my client wants. I tried to explain but he does want it to work that way

Comment: Stripe for WooCommerce does this: https://woocommerce.com/products/stripe/

Comment: Read in the documentation that it is only available in 25 countries, and mine is not one of them

Comment: PayPal is your next option then, perhaps this: https://www.storeapps.org/product/woocommerce-buy-now/

Comment: What do you mean?? I just want a one time special checkout, not a payment method

Comment: Checkout includes payment, yes?

Comment: I know, but how do I make that one time checkout? Let's say PayPal is my payment method

Comment: the plugin does that for you.

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions, but with "the plugin does it" you mean the stripe one or??

Comment: this PayPal/Buy Now plugin that I mentioned before: https://www.storeapps.org/product/woocommerce-buy-now/

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. It's late tonight (03am) will try it tomorrow to see if it works for me. Thank you so much

Comment: I'll post those two plugins in an Answer here. Glad i could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could code your own, and connect to a payment gateway's API, but plenty have tread this road before you so stand on their shoulders. Two possibilities:

[Stripe One Click Checkout plugin by WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/products/stripe/)

[PayPal One Click Checkout plugin by StoreApps](https://www.storeapps.org/product/woocommerce-buy-now/)

Comment: The Paypal one worked, but if you can provide the codes (that can do the same tasks as the plugin) I'd highly appreciate it.

Comment: Just want the codes for my future learning..

Comment: Sorry I don't have any of my own code for this, hence why I'd use one of the above plugins.